# Phonegap build cli-5.2.0 - plugin barcodescanner not firing

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am using phonegap build version cli-5.2.0 and the barcodescanner plugin.

I've added the plugin to the config.xml:

And then in my index.html page I've added:

```
<script>
function clickScan() {

alert('tester');

cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
      function (result) {
          alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
      }, 
      function (error) {
          alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
      }
   );


};
</script>
```

THen a button:

```
<button onclick="clickScan();">Scan</button>
```

The alert is coming out but the scanner is not opening.

What I'm I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.

I had to add:

```
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script src="barcodescanner.js"></script>
```

to the index.html page. That solved it in my case.